# How to map over each character in a string in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I have a function foo that takes in a character. I want to map that function over each character in a string.

```
fun foo (ch : char) =
    ch;
fun bar (str : string) =
    map foo [(str)];
```

Clearly this won't work due to a string being applied to a function that expects a char. So I tried using String.explode(str) to break it up into a char array, but then I can't seem to map over each char in the array and apply the char to the foo function.

```
fun foo (ch : char) =
     ch;
fun bar (str : string) =
    map foo [(String.explode(str))];
```

How can I map a function over each character in a string?

EDIT:
I wanted to change foo to take 2 parameters

```
fun foo(ch : char, i : int) =
    ch;
fun bar(str : string) =
    map foo (String.explode(str), 1);
```

But that gives me a tycon mismatch

```
operator domain: (char * int) list
operand:         char list * int
```

How come previously the String.explode(str) was understood by the map function to map over each char, but now it sees it as a full char list?

EDIT 2: Nevermind, figured it out.

```
fun bar(str : string) =
    map (fn x => foo (x, 1)) (String.explode(str));
```

Comment: If you want to avoid the costly explode/implode, you can also use `CharVector.map`, which has type `(char -> char) -> string -> string` (http://www.standardml.org/Basis/mono-vector.html#MONO_VECTOR:SIG:SPEC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to `map` over each character, then the list you give to `map` must be a list of characters. `explode` returns a list of characters, so using `explode` is definitely the right idea. But you're putting the list returned by `explode` into another list, resulting in a list *of lists* of characters. That's why you get a type error.

Just remove the outer list and your code will work as you intend.

Answer (score -1):

```
- String.map Char.succ "HAL";
> val it = "IBM" : string
```

Comment: A brief explanation would improve this answer.